# Evaluating a triple integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{1+x+y} f(x,y,z) dz \, dy\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{1+x+y} f(x,y,z) dz \, dy\, dx
\end{align*}

where $f(x,y,z)=1$

**My work so far**

\begin{align*}
  &\qquad= \int_0^1 \int_0^x \left(z\Big|_{z=0}^{z=1+x+y}\right)dy\, dx\\
  &\qquad= \int_0^1 \int_0^x (1+x+y) dy\, dx\\
  &\qquad= \int_0^1 \biggl[y + yx + \frac{y^2}{2}\biggr]_{y=0}^{y=x}  dx\\
  &\qquad= \int_0^1 \biggl(x + x^2 + \frac{x^2}{2}\biggr) dx\\
  &\qquad= \int_0^1 \biggl(x + \frac{3x^2}{2} \biggr) dx\\
  &\qquad= \biggl[\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{2} \biggr]_0^1
  = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1
\end{align*}

Would I be on the right path here?

Comment: Yes it seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did it correctly.

For this particular triple integral, you simply calculate it from the inside iteratively.

Since $f=1$, this integral calculates the volume of the subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$
S=\{(x,y,z):0<x<1, 0<y<x,0<z<1+x+y\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Laufen,

yes, it's right.

I also checked WolframAlpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=3a8a6afa299813f2a9b0d6269f5b9341